# Android adding fragment to end of layout

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am trying to add a `Fragment` to my `MainActivity`, and it works but I want to add it to the end of the layout. The reason I want to do this  is because in my layout I have included 5 fragments and I don't want to generate them all. I think it has to be done in the `onAttach()` method of the `Fragment` class but I don't have a clue how to do it. Any help is welcome.

This is my layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="ch.testhomespeed.lazar.test.MainActivity">

   <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true">

        <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:id="@+id/content_main"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
            tools:context="ch.testhomespeed.lazar.test.MainActivity"
            tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

            <include layout="@layout/fragment_header" />

            <include layout="@layout/fragment_first_apartment" />
            <include layout="@layout/fragment_second_apartment" />
            <include layout="@layout/fragment_third_apartment" />
            <include layout="@layout/fragment_fourth_apartment" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Could you share your code? and what exactly do you mean by adding it to the "end of the layout".

Comment: I have edited the question with the layout code

Comment: I want to put that fragment after the fourth_apartment fragment, but when I add the fragment it overlaps  the first fragment - header

Comment: are you trying to add it programatically? or literally code it into this layout? and is the fragment the same format at the other layouts? it's included in the layout? and it's overlapping?

Comment: I am trying to add it programatically, I don't want to include it because I can't replace it with another fragment